# using Riverpod to display data from a multiple api request

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

So I have a function that concurrently fetches two diffrent object models , but i'm having a problem trying to display these values by their respective models . So below is where I'm fetching the data that I want to display:

```
final getProfileAndItem = FutureProvider.family((ref, String uid) async {
  return ref.watch(itemUserProvider).getItemByUser(uid);
});

 Future<(UserTable, ItemModel)> getItemByUser(String uid) async {
    try {
      final value = await Future.wait([
        http.get(Uri.parse('${API.getpurchaseItemByUID}' '?uid=$uid')),
        http.get(Uri.parse('${API.getUserProfileByUID}' '?uid=$uid'))
      ]);

      final item = jsonDecode(value[0].body); 
      final profile = jsonDecode(value[1].body);

      return (UserTable.fromJson(profile[0]), ItemModel.fromJson(item[0]));
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Below is where i'm trying to display the data and where i'm getting the error ,it seems that every time I try to fetch a value by the model it belongs to I get `The getter  isn't defined for the type '(UserTable, itemModel)'.`

```
 ref.watch(getProfileAndItem(uid)).when(
              data: (data) => Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(data.userName),//UserTable
                    Text(data.itemName)//ItemModel
                  ],
                ),
              error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
              loading: () => const Loader(),
            ));
```

Comment: Which model has the `userName` and `itemName` fields? `UserTable` or `ItemModel`?

Comment: let me edit for contexts sake , but userName - UserTable and itemName is from ItemModel

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is a [Record](https://dart.dev/language/records) (`type '(UserTable, itemModel)'`), if you want to get `userName` and `itemName` from the `ItemModel` (which is the second value in the Record), you should access them like this:

```dart
data: (data) => Column(
  children: [
    Text(data.$2.userName),
    Text(data.$2.itemName)
  ],
),
```

Comment: this seems to have worked to remove the error at hand  , however the data doesnt seem to display even though there is data that is being fetched within the function

Comment: Have you tried to print the data before returning it in the `getItemByUser` method, and then compare to the result that is shown in these `Text` widgets?

Comment: yes I tried printing the values , and it does show and prove there are values im fetching from the api , only problem is the data is not getting displayed on the ui

Comment: Are you sure that is not a Widget sizing problem? Maybe try to replace the text inside `Text` with 'Hello world' and see if it's getting displayed?

Comment: thank you , i didnt even realize this . all is working well

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [Record](https://dart.dev/language/records), you can access the record item using the named parameter. For Example:

```
final getProfileAndItem = FutureProvider.family((ref, String uid) async {
  return ref.watch(itemUserProvider).getItemByUser(uid);
});

 Future<({UserTable userTable, ItemModel itemModel})> getItemByUser(String uid) async {
    try {
      final value = await Future.wait([
        http.get(Uri.parse('${API.getpurchaseItemByUID}' '?uid=$uid')),
        http.get(Uri.parse('${API.getUserProfileByUID}' '?uid=$uid'))
      ]);

      final item = jsonDecode(value[0].body); 
      final profile = jsonDecode(value[1].body);

      return (userTable: UserTable.fromJson(profile[0]), itemModel: ItemModel.fromJson(item[0]));
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Then you can use it as:

```
 ref.watch(getProfileAndItem(uid)).when(
          data: (data) => Column(
              children: [
                Text(data.userTable.userName),//UserTable
                Text(data.itemModel.itemName)//ItemModel
              ],
            ),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
          loading: () => const Loader(),
        ));
```